# ReactJS updating two components composed of lists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

TLDR: parent component renders child component -- logging properties in parent and child -- logs show different data

**solution found from here:** https://hackernoon.com/common-pitfall-in-initialising-state-based-on-props-in-react-js-d56795a944aa

I have two lists (using react-infinite) like the picture here:

[image]

When a user clicks *Add* from the left list, the item **should** be added to the right list and removed from the left list.

I have the following logic for "adding" and "removing" (quotations because of immutability) from the lists -- I don't think the issue is here.

```
addItem(id) {
    const item = this.state.available.find(x => x.id == id);
    const filteredArray = this.state.available.filter(x => x != item);
    this.setState({
        existing: this.state.existing.concat([item]),
        available: filteredArray
    });
};
```

I have a function called `renderAvailableChildNodes()` that renders the left list (called after the `this.setState()` call). In the beginning of that function I log the list `console.log(this.state.available);`.

Here's the function.

```
renderAvailableChildNodes() {
    console.log(this.state.available);
    return (
        this.state.available.map((item, index) => 
            <div key={index}>
                <MenuItem 
                    index={index} 
                    id={item.id} 
                    name={item.name}
                    onAdd={this.addItem}
                    onDelete={this.rmItem}
                    onEdit={this.editItem} />
                <hr/>
            </div>
        )
    );
};
```

Here's the odd part. That log message is correct. Here's the log after I added `Item 1` like in the picture.

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
{id: "456", name: "item 2"}
{id: "789", name: "item 3"}
{id: "987", name: "item 4"}
{id: "654", name: "item 5"}
{id: "321", name: "item 6"}
{id: "159", name: "item 7"}
{id: "357", name: "item 8"}
```

I also log the state in the `MenuItem` component -- **and I am showing different data**

Here's the full component.

```
class MenuItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: props.id,
            name: props.name,
            index: props.index,
            onAdd: props.onAdd,
            onDelete: props.onDelete,
            onEdit: props.onEdit,
        };
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.id);
        console.log(this.state.name);
        return (
            <div key={this.state.index}>
                <Typography type="h4">{this.state.name}</Typography>
                <Typography type="h5">{this.state.id}</Typography>
                <ButtonGroup className="mr-2">
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={() => this.state.onAdd(this.state.id)}>Add</Button>
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={() => this.state.onDelete(this.state.id)}>Remove</Button>
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={() => this.state.onEdit(this.state.id)}>Edit</Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

And the log messages.

```
MenuItem.js:23 123
MenuItem.js:24 item 1
MenuItem.js:23 456
MenuItem.js:24 item 2
MenuItem.js:23 789
MenuItem.js:24 item 3
MenuItem.js:23 987
MenuItem.js:24 item 4
MenuItem.js:23 654
MenuItem.js:24 item 5
MenuItem.js:23 321
MenuItem.js:24 item 6
MenuItem.js:23 159
MenuItem.js:24 item 7
MenuItem.js:23 123
MenuItem.js:24 item 1
```

**UPDATE**

Per suggestion, I replaced `concat` with a spread operator, and also added logging inside my `renderAvailableChildNodes()` function, but the problem persist. Here's what my `addItem()` function looks like.

```
addItem(id) {
    const item = this.state.available.find(x => x.id == id);
    const filteredArray = this.state.available.filter(x => x != item);
    this.setState({
        existing: [...this.state.existing,item],
        available: filteredArray
    });
};
```

I added logging here.

```
renderAvailableChildNodes() {
    console.log(this.state.available);
    return (
        this.state.available.map((item, index) => console.log(item) ||
            <div key={index}>
                <MenuItem 
                ...
```

And I can see that it is still logging the correct list in the parent component and the incorrect list in child component.

```
CreatePage.js:124 {id: "456", name: "item 2"}
CreatePage.js:124 {id: "789", name: "item 3"}
CreatePage.js:124 {id: "987", name: "item 4"}
CreatePage.js:124 {id: "654", name: "item 5"}
CreatePage.js:124 {id: "321", name: "item 6"}
CreatePage.js:124 {id: "159", name: "item 7"}
CreatePage.js:124 {id: "357", name: "item 8"}
MenuItem.js:23 123
MenuItem.js:24 item 1
MenuItem.js:23 456
MenuItem.js:24 item 2
MenuItem.js:23 789
MenuItem.js:24 item 3
MenuItem.js:23 987
MenuItem.js:24 item 4
MenuItem.js:23 654
MenuItem.js:24 item 5
MenuItem.js:23 321
MenuItem.js:24 item 6
MenuItem.js:23 159
MenuItem.js:24 item 7
MenuItem.js:23 123
MenuItem.js:24 item 1
```

*Why is this happening:* note that the `MenuItem` logs show `item 1` twice -- as if it is replacing `item 8` from the original list, but in the html DOM the behavior is that `item 8` is removed, and there is still only the one original `item 1`

Maybe the issue is where the render function is being called in the parent component?

```
<Row>
    <Col md={6}>
        <CardHeader>Available Child Nodes</CardHeader>
        <CardBody>
            <Infinite elementHeight={8} containerHeight={600}>
                {this.renderAvailableChildNodes()}
            </Infinite>
        </CardBody>
    </Col>
    <Col md={6}>
        <CardHeader>Existing Child Nodes</CardHeader>
        <CardBody>
            <Infinite elementHeight={8} containerHeight={600}>
                {this.renderExistingChildNodes()}
            </Infinite>
        </CardBody>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: why dont you use Redux and put your state in one store ?

Comment: What does your main render method look like? I mean the one where you would be rendering your lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging inside your map method to know which all items are getting called. Something like this:

```
this.state.available.map((item, index) => console.log(item) ||
   <div key={index}>
            <MenuItem 
                index={index} 
                id={item.id} 
                name={item.name}
                onAdd={this.addItem}
                onDelete={this.rmItem}
                onEdit={this.editItem} />
            <hr/>
        </div>
    )
```

if you find first item is also getting called then might be problem in updating the list.

Comment: hmm I added the logging and it seems to be logging the correct list still in the parent component -- check the question for updates

Comment: yeah as you pointed out `componentWillRecieveProps` will work that was the first thing i got in my mind but in latest update of React it is deprecated .

Answer (score 0):

the problem is most likely immutability of state. you are directly modifying the state in your add item function. instead try this. using spread operator you are not modifying the state directly

```
addItem(id) {
    const item = this.state.available.find(x => x.id == id);
    const filteredArray = this.state.available.filter(x => x != item);
    this.setState({
        existing: [...this.state.existing,item]
        available: filteredArray
    });
};
```

Comment: ah yes the spread operator (still new to react). unfortunately this did not resolve the bug. I also added additional logging, check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The issue was that my **child component was setting state in the constructor.** According to the article linked below, the constructor is called only at mount time. If a parent is re-rendered, the child is not necessarily re-mounted -- thus I has to define a special function `componentWillReceiveProps()` and update the state (via `setState()`) in this function.

Check out this article: https://hackernoon.com/common-pitfall-in-initialising-state-based-on-props-in-react-js-d56795a944aa